# Do I have to delete struct pointer manually in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, struct

Somebody told me that I don't necessarily have to delete struct pointer manually.
From what I understand you must `delete` everything that is allocated with `new`, even structs, right?

Comment: Yes, right. Somebody was wrong.

Comment: Yes. But here's a tip: if you use something called `unique_ptr` you don't have to worry about new and delete. Google it ;^)

Comment: @tux3 I would say you don't have to worry about `delete`, but you already need to use `new`. e.g.: `std::unique_ptr<A> p(new A);`

Comment: @j.a. Thankfully we have make_unique now

Comment: Yes, since C++14. So, you're technically right.

Answer (score 2):

Right, you must.
As with everything else, if you allocated memory fore something, you are responsible for releasing it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use smart pointers as for example `std::unique_ptr`. It would call its own deleter when the object of the structure was destroyed.

Otherwise you indeed have to call operator delete or delete [] provided that the structure is the owner of the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Of course when you `new` any type (`int`, `char`, ..., `MyClass`, `MyStruct`) you are reserving some memory, so you will need to free it later yourself.

`delete` for any `new`

`delete[]` for any `new[]`
...

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need a `delete` for every `new`, `delete []` for every `new []`, `fclose` for every `fopen` and all the other varieties.

Still, you need not neccessarily write it yourself, if you delegate it to a smart-pointer for example, like `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`.
You should do that on general principles anyway!

Also, there actually are a few circumstances in which never de-allocating is appropriate, like if you store some data you will have to keep until the end of the program, unless the destructor does something important.

Actually, there's no need to bother sweeping the carpets when the house gets demolished, and it would have a negative performance impact, which might easily get unacceptibly big.
Think about it "Come here (page in), so I can dismiss you (free)." seems a bit pointless or even spiteful.